# Does the electric current inside a wire fluctuate when the wire shape is changed while still having it connected to the terminals?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

The electric current inside a wire depends on the electric field across the infinitesimal segments that the wire consists of. If we readjust the shape of the wire, i.e. make changes to the conducting path of the electrons externally while still keeping the terminal connections as well as the length of the wire intact, does that affect the individual infinitesimal electric fields? If it does, then does that affect the magnitude of the current flowing inside the wire temporarily?

P.S. Edit: By "fluctuations" I mean the following:
1. In case of a steady DC current, momentary variation in the steady current exclusively due to the shaking and reshaping of the wire.

2. In case of any fluctuating DC or AC current momentary variations in the rms current exclusively due to the shaking or reshaping of the wire.

Comment: Define what "fluctuate" means.  If the current changes by 0.001%, is this a fluctuation?

Comment: Good point. I shall make an edit clarifying what I mean by "fluctuations".